# How to load SKTextureAtlas texture from plist file

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction, sktexture, sktextureatlas

I need to load texture images from plist file to be used for SKTextureAtlas. I have made this using the images as frames manually, i. e. run action with textures. But now I have compacted the images in one .png and added their data to the .plist file.

How can I load the texture from this plist file ?

Comment: why do you need to load texture images from plist files?  what does your plist even look like?

Comment: To better manage memory. It i like the cocos2D plist, where we save all frames in one png image and add plist for their metadata. I have a .png with all frames side by side and a .plist file with their frames determined. The problem is that I can't load the frames from the plist directly into the SKTextureAtlas.

Comment: i don't use cocos2d, sorry.  The atlas is managing the memory for you,  and can be created before you even compile,  loading a plist into `SKTextureAtlas` seems like it is a waste of time.  Just create a folder called `<description>.atlas`  put all your images into the atlas, and then call `SKTextureAtlas(named:<description>)`